# How can I validate a user through AD in my WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, active-directory

I have a WebAPI in which I required the user to provide their username/password so that I can validate and authenticate through active directory.

Using the PrincipleContext I validate the user like:

```
isValidated = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
```

However how can I require the user to pass me their password in order to validate the user?

Obviously I don't want hem to send the actual string, and converting it to Base64String isn't encrypting the data since it could easily be converted back to the original value.

I tried playing around with Rcf2898 but that only appears for encrypting and not decrypting values.

How can I validate a user through AD in my WebAPI?

Comment: You're better off with an intermediary token service like ADFS or even an IDP like Facebook - depending on the sensitivity of your api data.  Otherwise, standup a UI to gather the creds and pass to your api.

Comment: You may use SSL